# Is there any module or software with a updated database to avoid these kind of requests?

Tags: webserver, firewall

Just in 24 hours I've checked in my webserver requests like these ones.
Is there any Apache module or firewall to avoid all these junk requests (and others for sure I will receive)?

It would be interesting to be able to have an update list and/or to be able to add custom rules, for example I don't have a Wordpress so I'll add all the "wp" ones.

I know how to block this at code level, and htaccess level, but I wonder if there's any module or service more robust, updated and customizable.

```
/.env
/.well-known/assetlinks.json
/.well-known/security.txt
/_ignition/execute-solution
/actuator/health
/app-assets/data/search.json
/console/
/dns-query?dns=(.*)
(.*)/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/news/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/site/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/test/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/web/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/website/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/wp/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/wp1/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/wp2/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
(.*)/xmlrpc.php?rsd=
/login
/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https%3A%2F%2F1%2Fecp%2F
/remote/fgt_lang?lang=%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2Fdev%2Fcmdb%2Fsslvpn_websession
/sitemap.xml
/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php
/wordpress/wp-login.php
/wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/readme.txt
/wp-login.php
/wp/wp-login.php
```